# Why did i have to convert the variables?

Tags: python

```
def main():
    account_value = input("Enter your account value: ")
    AV = account_value
    years = input("Enter how many years you want to save: ")
    IR = input("enter the interest rate per year: ")
    for i in range(int(years)):
        aftervalue = int(AV) + (float(IR)*int(AV))
    print(aftervalue)
```

Why did i have to convert them in the expression in the loop?

Why werent they already treated as ints and a float?

Comment: In Python 3, `input()` returns a string, it doesn't parse the input.

Comment: Why are you assigning the same variable with the same expression in a loop? it's the same thing each time.

Comment: Don't convert them in the loop, convert them once when you assign the variables, e.g. `years = int(input("Enter years: "))`

Comment: thanks. 
 
"Why are you assigning the same variable with the same expression in a loop? it's the same thing each time. "  because im a noob just started 2 days ago lol. and thanks, i didnt know that about the input. I mean, the program worked, so i didnt realize i was doing something else wrong too

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, `input()` returns a string. If you want to use it in arithmetic operations, you have to convert it to `int` or `float` first.

You don't need to do it in the loop, it's best to do it just once when you assign the variables.

If you ran your script in Python 2, you wouldn't need to do the conversions. Its `input()` function evaluates the input as a Python expression, you have to use `raw_input()` to get the original input as a string.

Comment: thank you 

`def main():`
 `account_value = input("Enter your account value: ")`


 `AV = int(account_value)`

 `years = int(input("Enter how many years you want to save: "))`

 `IR = float(input("enter the interest rate per year: "))`

 `for i in range(years):`
  `aftervalue = AV + (IR*AV)`
 `print(aftervalue)`
  `

it looks like this now and it works still. it makes more sense too. the main thing was that i didnt know input treated everything as strings (i also dont know how to format the code properly in the comments) :(

Comment: Don't post code in comments, there's no formatting.